# Chaos in discrete space and time systems. Definition, tests, etc?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, cellular-automata

I have been working with a cellular automata model and have been struggling to characterize its dynamics. It seems to be displaying aperiodic behaviour in a certain part of the parameter space, but I am really struggling to quantify/qualify this. I can't really find a definition nor, as you would expect from lack of definition, test for chaos in this system. I have found some sources that are heavy on topology which I know next to nothing about so I really have no gauge as to how promising/reliable they are (I'm on a bit of a time crunch so I want to avoid taking that detour if possible).

I found the following:
http://bluebox.ippt.pan.pl/~tlipnia/docs/js_Discrete_Chaos_IEEE.pdf
which was really interesting, but hasn't been that helpful since my space doesn't have a well defined metric.

Does anybody have interesting papers, ideas, resources, etc. on the subject?

Anything is appreciated (even the Topology heavy stuff for possible future readers of this post and/or myself if all else fails).

Thank you.

Comment: *since my space doesn't have a well defined metric* – I am pretty confident that the existence of some notion of distance is fundamental to describing and defining chaos. For interacting cellular automata, I would suggest something like the number of state changes needed to transform one system into the other.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267175/how-can-i-prove-that-game-of-lifes-evolution-function-is-continuous) can also be useful.